# How to achieve a two column layout on a user registration form

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

I want to make a two column, for the "First Name & Last Name" fields, for our registration form.

http://ellobo375.provenreviews.com/

I've tried using the following code:

```
input#first_name-651 { width: 50% !important; float: left !important;}

input#last_name-651 { width: 50% !important; float: right !important;}
```

Comment: err it applies 100% to this question - your question is off topic as there is not information in the question to replicate your problem and I was showing you how to fix it - you cannot just paste a link to your website, if you do not want to follow thew rules then don't complain and don't moan when people try to help you  by pointing out the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `div.userpro-field.userpro-field-first_name` and `div.userpro-field.userpro-field-last_name` (which seem to be wrapping the first name and last name fields) to be both `float: left` and `width: 50%`.

Between them, there seems to be an element with class `userpro-clear`. Remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I've check your code.

```
            <div class="userpro-field  userpro-field-first_name " data-key="first_name"><div class="userpro-label"><label for="first_name-294">First Name</label></div><div class="userpro-input"><input name="first_name-294" id="first_name-294" value="" placeholder="" data-ajaxcheck="" data-help="" data-label="First Name" data-placeholder="" data-add_condition="show" data-condition_fields="first_name" data-condition_rule="select" data-condition_value="" data-_builtin="1" data-hidden="0" data-hideable="0" data-html="0" data-locked="0" data-private="0" data-required="0" data-type="text" data-woo="0" type="text"><div class="userpro-clear"></div></div></div><div class="userpro-clear"></div>               

            <div class="userpro-field  userpro-field-last_name " data-key="last_name"><div class="userpro-label"><label for="last_name-294">Last Name</label></div><div class="userpro-input"><input name="last_name-294" id="last_name-294" value="" placeholder="" data-ajaxcheck="" data-help="" data-label="Last Name" data-placeholder="" data-add_condition="show" data-condition_fields="first_name" data-condition_rule="select" data-condition_value="" data-_builtin="1" data-hidden="0" data-hideable="0" data-html="0" data-locked="0" data-private="0" data-required="0" data-type="text" data-woo="0" type="text"><div class="userpro-clear"></div></div></div><div class="userpro-clear"></div>
```

After your "div class=userpro-field", you have a "div class=userpro-clear"

your class userpro-clear have this CSS rule:

```
div.userpro-clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

If you have a div with clear between two floating divs, float never apply. You need to delete this div between these two fields.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting both to inline-block?